# How to Check the Logged In User of Laravel 4 in Laravel 5 using Same DB?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have to work with two Projects one of which is in Laravel 4 and the other is in Laravel 5.

The scenario is that the user will always logged into the Laravel 4 project. and Laravel 5 project is used to their to provide some 30% functionality of the over all project.

I've integrated both Laravel 4 and Laravel 5 project.

What I want to do is that if a user is not logged into Laravel 4 project they should not be able to access the Larvel 5 project's routes (should be redirected to log in page using middleware), and if a user is logged in Laravel 4 project he could be able to access the routes of laravel 5 project.

But the problem for me is that these two are separate projects which are using single database. and I'm not able to access the data of the logged in user via 'Auth::user()->property' in Laravel 5 project as the user logged into Laravel 4 Project.

Is there any method to use Laravel 4 project's logged in user's data in Laravel 5 via Auth::user(), Auth::check() or Auth::guest() methods????

Comment: try creating a symbolic link for `session` folder inside `storage` folder

Comment: I'm using 'redis' for sessions. Would your suggestion also work with 'redis' as well?

Comment: then you should see if redis supports session sharing or is there any other workaround to make redis think that both the systems are same.